# Entity Framework inserting wrong data?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a piece of code where I am updating a record in my database, copying that object using [ValueInjector](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/) and then attempting to add that new object to my database using Entity framework:

```
//Get record to update
File currentFile = db.Files.First(t => t.FileId == updatedFile.FileId && t.CustomerId == PrimaryUser);
currentFile.ToLanguage = 2; //update that record
File copy = Helpers.CopyFile(currentFile); //copy the currentFile
copy.FileId = Guid.NewGuid();
copy.ToLanguage = 3;
copy.Project = null;
db.Files.Add(copy); //add new record to the database
db.SaveChanges();
```

Definition for CopyFile:

```
public static VerbalInk.Data.File CopyFile(Data.File source)
{
    Data.File newFile = new Data.File();
    newFile.InjectFrom(source);
    return newFile;
}
```

When I place a breakpoint at my `db.Files.Add(copy);` line and then view `copy.ToLanguage` it has the expected value of `3`, but for some reason when I save my changes to the database both records have a value of 2 for `ToLanguage`.

Does anyone have any idea why this would be happening and how I can get the correct value for `ToLanguage` inserted?

**UPDATE:**

I have found that if I disable Lazy Loading for my data context using the line below:

```
db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

then everything updates as expected.  Can someone explain why this would happen?  Is there a way I can get my code working without disabling lazy loading?

`File` definition:

```
public partial class File
{
    public File()
    {
        this.FileServices = new HashSet<FileService>();
        this.FileAudioVariables = new HashSet<FileAudioVariable>();
        this.FileLanguages = new HashSet<FileLanguage>();
    }

    public System.Guid FileId { get; set; }
    public System.Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> TemplateId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> OrderId { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public bool IsMailInFile { get; set; }
    public string FileUrl { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> NumberOfSpeakers { get; set; }
    public int AudioLength { get; set; }
    public int BillableMinutes { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> StatusId { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public string VirtualType { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime UploadDate { get; set; }
    public bool Tracked { get; set; }
    public bool Exported { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsConverting { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsInfected { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> OrderDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DueDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> TranscriptionistId { get; set; }
    public string TranscriptionistNotes { get; set; }
    public int BillingStatusId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> ProjectId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Specialized { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> TurnaroundId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> FromLanguage { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ToLanguage { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> ParentFileId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<FileService> FileServices { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FileAudioVariable> FileAudioVariables { get; set; }
    public virtual ServiceTurnaround ServiceTurnaround { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FileLanguage> FileLanguages { get; set; }
    public virtual Language Language { get; set; }
    public virtual Language Language1 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, had a bit of a moment there.... weird... my eyes just skipped it entirely... Compare the GUID of both objects, are they the same by any chance?

Comment: No the GUID is unique between both objects.

Comment: Can you add the definition for the File Entity? I suspect that you have both a ForeignKey integer (ToLanguage) which is a value type and a property which relates to the language entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@a-h has reason, if lazy loading is enabled, the `InjectFrom` method should copy all the properties of the `source` File, even the navigation properties. This way, when you change the `ToLanguage` FK property value in the `copy` File, EF ignore that value and save the changes based in the `Language` navigation property you have already a set before.
I think the order of the transactions is important here, first EF should update the `ToLanguage` FK row in the `File` Table related to the `source` File and after that, it should insert the `copy` File.

If you disable lazy loading, your navigation properties aren't loaded and they are not updated in the `copy` File, that's way when you set the `ToLanguage` FK property, the relationship is saved as you want.

If you want to work with lazy loading, I suggest you set in `null` that navigation property (`Language`) before save the changes.